# Count the number of rows in SQL table grouped by a particular column and filter by regex

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have an SQL table (in Google BigQuery) like below

```
task_id  text 
1        F45
2        test
1        G890  
3        test_a
3        H789
4        test_c
4        test_d
```

I want to count the number of unique `task_id` which has at least 1 of its text entry passes this regex `r"\b[a-zA-Z]+\b"`. In this case, there will be 3 unique `task_id`, which are `task_id` 2,3 and 4, because all entries that correspond to `task_id` 1 will return null with that regex.

Below query doesn't seem right because it doesn't group by the `task_id`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(task_id))
FROM <table_name>
WHERE
(
  SELECT task_id, REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(name, "\b[a-zA-Z]+\b")
)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `GROUP BY` as  else you get only 1 scalar value

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(task_id))
FROM <table_name>
WHERE
(
  SELECT task_id, REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(name, "\b[a-zA-Z]+\b")
)
GROUP BY task_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define group by clause at the end and it should work fine.just put group by task_id at last of your SQL statement.